# Aborting an Ajax request if confirmation dialog is "Cancel"

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I'd like to have a `<f:ajax>` component that would display a confirmation dialog and then do the `action` tag if `OK` was selected or abort if `Cancel` was selected.
I thought this would work, but it doesn't (The ajax part runs no matter what I select in the confirmation):

```
<f:ajax render="some_div">
<h:commandButton value="A Hazardous Button!"
  onclick="show_confirm()" action="#{bean.doSomething}" />
</f:ajax>
```

-

```
function show_confirm()
{
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to do this? This is totally hazardous!");
    if (r==true)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you need to add the `return` keyword to your onclick handler... try changing `onclick="show_confirm()"` to `onclick="return show_confirm()"`

secondly, you can simplify your function to:

```
function show_confirm()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to do this? This is totally hazardous!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For JSF ajax you can do with following way.

```
<script>
function show_confirm()
{
  return confirm("Are you sure you want to do this? This is totally hazardous!");
}
</script>

<h:commandButton value="A Hazardous Button!" onclick="return show_confirm()">
 <f:ajax listener=#{bean.doSomething}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```